# Can the FWP format of Expression Web 4.0 export web package be converted to a zip?

Tags: expression-web

Expression Web 4.0 has the ability to export content and it's dependencies (a partial website). The format it exports in is a Microsoft Expression Web 4 Web Package (.fwp). Has anyone found a utility to convert this to a zip?

Answer (score 0):

That's why I get for not actually investigating further. Turns out the first four bytes are 4D 53 43 46 (MSCF) which means that it's a CAB file with a different extension.

It contains all the files which have been renamed and flattened, as well as a manifest.xml.

Should be a short exercise with XSD.exe from here to make use of it.